# jQuery click event won't work?

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I am trying to trigger a click on an anchor tag and it doesn't seem to work?

```
<a id="pop" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Pop This</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {     
    function libertyPop() {
        $("#pop").click(function(){ console.log(this)});
    }        

    libertyPop();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a `click` event you just use `el.click()` without any arguments.

Your current code is attaching an event to execute when the element is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

There is your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/gKqXG/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $('body').on('click', '#pop', function() {
       alert('clicked'); 
    });

    $("#pop").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(this) is not referring to any property of tag from what I can see.

If your looking to log the URL, replace "this" with $(this).attr("href")
if your looking to log the text between the tags, try $(this).text()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
$('a#pop')[0].click();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvKGZ/1/)